# docker containers give out blank ipv6 address

Tags: linux, networking, docker, ipv6, gentoo

I am trying to develop simple swarm service with docker, I am using below docker compose file

```
version: '3.2'

services:
    sessions:
        image: redis:4
        ports:
            - 6379:6379
        networks:
           web:
               aliases:
                   - redis
    cowsay-service:
        image: spsarolkar/cowsay
        ports:
                - 8000
        environment:
            - SERVICE_PORTS=8000
        deploy:
            replicas: 5
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
                max_attempts: 3
                window: 120s
        networks:
             - web

    cowsay-proxy:
        image: dockercloud/haproxy
        depends_on:
            - cowsay-service
        environment:
            - BALANCE=leastconn
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        ports:
                - "8000:80"
        networks:
            web:
                aliases:
                    - cowsay

    cowsay-ui:
        image: spsarolkar/cowsay-ui
        ports:
                - "[::1]:8080:8080"
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - cowsay
        networks:
            - web

networks:
        web:
           driver: overlay
```

When I try to reach my service at 8080 using `curl -v http://localhost:8080` , the connection is successful but I do not receive any output and the request hangs indefinitely as below

```
sunils@sunils-pc /mnt/share/sunils/repos/github/ec2-sample-docker $ curl -v http://localhost:8080
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8080/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.0
> Accept: */*
>
```

Although I can access the service when I use ipv4 `curl -v http://localhost:8080`

```
sunils@sunils-pc /mnt/share/sunils/repos/github/ec2-sample-docker $ curl -4 -v http://localhost:8080
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8080/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=9dce2aac-30dd-434d-b0ad-8858e412f4ad; Path=/
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Language: en-US
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Thu, 27 Sep 2018 15:57:27 GMT
< 
<!doctype html>
...
```

I already have enabled the ipv6 on local machine and docker also has the ipv6 enabled

```
10: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:93:8b:01:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:db8:1::1/64 scope global tentative 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1/64 scope link tentative 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: docker_gwbridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:0c:29:e9:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global docker_gwbridge
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:cff:fe29:e928/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

When I inspect my network using `docker network inspect prod_web`, I see that there are no ip v6 address assigned to containers

```
[
    {
        "Name": "prod_web",
        "Id": "finyqtzsvgceyzfqak83burjz",
        "Created": "2018-09-26T23:42:49.383967019+05:30",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.0.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "13f94f6444f8109c546c2e4124993e4431f857128ddbc0c6245485e91d675360": {
                "Name": "prod_cowsay-service.2.l2jbq045g8evyjvgsn1253t1t",
                "EndpointID": "4f096fb212347335874cdb3816ae259516ff05c28fd7aaef0a8dda886596e0e1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.5/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "2a361c5d113c46aa98192a2e83281215f67ba1db51ea4486ae7379806ba02027": {
                "Name": "prod_cowsay-ui.1.69npxb9xv2epx3n5yi2ysvd3t",
                "EndpointID": "f0a206ffbfaf000e89c11b9a5c3ba05d2c9892b7ac346007ec5d8dc9633f250b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.4/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "2a6c7ff057a4925512a37efd9f8de46904c07a2791f635ee8dbd0e6aa41789df": {
                "Name": "prod_cowsay-service.1.45qqm0ccey6gdnq1yykayc7vi",
                "EndpointID": "c972bbfb01efe87aa76696143959e7713c41a96c9e6c65eeedc20fafa48994f8",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:0e",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.14/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "6314a118b79d52bf0d8b94111046a7f1d191df2b53a72015bf4bc151a1693d2e": {
                "Name": "prod_cowsay-service.5.vx04rz82ofp1mhaoptt65hndk",
                "EndpointID": "8c73e4ec8af0cdc7c15ef9ee7b27f727dc0e5f6f002c5ec8d97cd7578c3cbe97",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:06",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.6/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "91fe104922b48f5d3152af2dfdae17b814bf4b9b8e54af6578c95d8cd0789d40": {
                "Name": "prod_cowsay-service.4.mj2r0b6v67z18yoojzq28ux1t",
                "EndpointID": "284d25741cbd3b9a3edc8ab1e4302cf3ff05f0f2e13c898608c45521e495c141",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:0c",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.12/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e1230af527d57cf71847e50ade05b5f207cd6448e6377cb050e3a920a3d62fb7": {
                "Name": "prod_cowsay-service.3.o11gy8bgxzifj158t7nvabcxk",
                "EndpointID": "a3c952e5f1baa0f36e9a5f375bf90a4f3a4016999e6de6afd13e95e1004d3310",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:08",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.8/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f4cc204b25b74ab49916fb5cbe45a1fb1267242578a1daaa7421b9360e8d9e0d": {
                "Name": "prod_sessions.1.eug36ekd0ll6m7bscv1n1vj84",
                "EndpointID": "0fb9edf81dae304f75cc61b7dba52ac541a6db058d01b019b05e0adf0e91581d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:07",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.7/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f8924c272bb67ab5681a62e55d4c5cbbddb09cc5258cbb766411ab6acc657459": {
                "Name": "prod_cowsay-proxy.1.oqvnqz37axyoa6l36vfrn3isv",
                "EndpointID": "337c7fc2b768a06b2cb25aec46f5e50e1dde9906b4c5c0af4003341bdd9900b3",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:0a",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.10/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4097"
        },
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.stack.namespace": "prod"
        },
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "3673f88acdca",
                "IP": "192.168.0.11"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am not sure if blank ipv6 address is the root cause, can someone please help me with resolving above problem