# How to create docker ingress network with ipv6 support

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, docker

I am trying to figure out issue with my docker network setup, ([docker containers give out blank ipv6 address](https://serverfault.com/questions/932987/docker-containers-give-out-blank-ipv6-address))

I am not able to reach the service over ipv6 on localhost, I have to use `curl -4 http://localhost:8080` instead of `curl http://localhost:8080`

While investigation I found out that the docker ingress network does not have ipv6 enabled, so I created removed older one and created new ingress network with ipv6 address

```
sunils@sunils-pc ~ $ docker network inspect ingress
[
    {
        "Name": "ingress",
        "Id": "8sn7034q646ayadix9nmsmv50",
        "Created": "2018-09-29T04:42:10.857389865Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": true,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.11.0.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "172.11.0.1"
                },
                {
                    "Subnet": "2002:ac0b:0000::/48",
                    "Gateway": "2002:ac0b::1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": true,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": null,
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4106,4107"
        },
        "Labels": null
    }
]
```

Also created new overlay network `ipv6_overlay` that I would be using from my containers,

```
sunils@sunils-pc ~ $ docker network inspect ipv6_overlay
[
    {
        "Name": "ipv6_overlay",
        "Id": "n7fv85sqhm0wd1ekpo8evnit2",
        "Created": "2018-09-29T06:47:17.363996665Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": true,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.10.0.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "172.10.0.1"
                },
                {
                    "Subnet": "2002:ac0a:0000::/48",
                    "Gateway": "2002:ac0a::1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": null,
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4113,4114"
        },
        "Labels": null
    }
]
```

I configured my container to use the overlay network ipv6_overlay with predefined ip addresses,

```
sunils@sunils-pc /mnt/share/sunils/repos/github/ec2-sample-docker $ cat docker-compose.yml 
version: '3.2'

services:
    sessions:
        image: redis:4
        ports: 
            - 6379:6379
        networks:
           web:
               ipv4_address: 172.10.0.10
               ipv6_address: 2002:ac0a:0000::10
               aliases:
                   - redis
    cowsay-service:
        image: spsarolkar/cowsay 
        ports:
                - 8000
        environment:
            - SERVICE_PORTS=8000
        deploy:
            replicas: 5
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
                max_attempts: 3
                window: 120s
        networks:
                web:
                    ipv4_address: 172.10.0.9
                    ipv6_address: 2002:ac0a:0000::9


    cowsay-proxy:
        image: dockercloud/haproxy
        depends_on:
            - cowsay-service
        environment: 
            - BALANCE=leastconn
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        ports:
                - "8000:80"
        networks:
            web:
               ipv4_address: 172.10.0.8
               ipv6_address: 2002:ac0a:0000::8
               aliases:
                    - cowsay

    cowsay-ui:
        image: spsarolkar/cowsay-ui
        ports:
                - "[::1]:8080:8080"
        depends_on:
            - redis 
            - cowsay
        networks:
            web:
               ipv4_address: 172.10.0.7
               ipv6_address: 2002:ac0a:0000::7

networks:
        web:
                external:
                        name: ipv6_overlay
```

But when I start my swarm services I get error in `/var/log/docker.log` as,

```
time="2018-09-29T12:09:19.693307864+05:30" level=error msg="fatal task error" error="Invalid address 2002:ac0b::2: It does not belong to any of this network's subnets" module=node/agent/taskmanager node.id=luqw5to6dike43h88h25xj7tg service.id=tfttw36jqmsq3ew6wzn61gyku task.id=7jo89apxj585pdtacmr2d7jpe
```

I am not sure even when I specified my own overlay network in the docker compose its falling back to ingress network. I get same error when I do not specify any ip addresses.

Can someone please help me with this

Comment: The IPv6 addresses in your docker-compose.yml are not in the same subnet as the IPv6 subnet you specified in your ingress and ipv6_overlay networks. Perhaps it's a typo?

Comment: HI Michael, the ipv6_overlay address I have just corrected, actually I the value "Subnet": "2002:ac0b:0000::/48" should have been '"Subnet": "2002:ac0a:0000::/48"

But even after updating the ipv6_overlay it gives the same error

Comment: Well, I've opened a github issue for this... https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41624 Invalid address ... It does not belong to any of this network's subnets (ipv6)

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same situation, and so far I have not come up with an actual solution, but rather a simple workaround. I tried creating different types of `ingress` networks, modifying the `docker_gwbridge` and whatnot, but IPv6 support is just bad. Even in this day and age..

So the workaround I came up with is `socat`. I created a small `systemd` service that starts after `docker.service` so it ought to be fairly resilient. Let's say your actual service wants to listen on port 8080, so instead make it listen on 8081 and socat IPv6 connections from 8080 to 8081.

```
socat -ly TCP6-LISTEN:8080,fork,reuseaddr,bind=<my_ipv6_addr> TCP:0.0.0.0:8081
```

The bind there is optional, but handy if you want to limit access. The `systemd` unit is as follows (`/etc/systemd/system/swarm-socat@.service`):

```
[Unit]
Description=socat for docker swarm (%i)
After=docker.service

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=/etc/socat-%i.conf
ExecStart=/usr/bin/socat -ly TCP6-LISTEN:${SOURCEPORT},fork,reuseaddr TCP:0.0.0.0:${TARGETPORT}
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and the env file just contains two lines which give it the ports, for example (`/etc/socat-viz.conf`):

```
SOURCEPORT=8080
TARGETPORT=8081
```

The service I'm running in the example is the [Docker Swarm visualizer](https://github.com/dockersamples/docker-swarm-visualizer).

```
docker service create \
  --name=viz \
  --publish published=8081,target=8080 \
  --constraint=node.role==manager \
  --mount=type=bind,src=/var/run/docker.sock,dst=/var/run/docker.sock \
  dockersamples/visualizer
```

Then simply enable and start the `systemd` service and you're good to go.

```
sudo systemctl enable swarm-socat@viz.service
sudo systemctl start swarm-socat@viz.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Swarm mode doesn't appear to support IPv6 with the ingress/service-mesh networking. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24379) on this that I'd recommend subscribing to and adding your thumbs up to get more attention, though at this point, it's going to be up to the community or Mirantis to provide an update (Docker doesn't have any developers assigned to it last I heard).

As a workaround, you can skip ingress, deploy a global service with "host" networking mode that will receive both IPv4 and IPv6. And if that service is a proxy (like traefik), it can then route requests to each container in the cluster using overlay networking and the container's IPv4 address. Here's a partial compose file with the key settings:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  proxy:
    deploy:
      mode: global
    ports:
    - target: 80
      published: 80
      protocol: "tcp"
      mode: "host"
    # ...
```